# 18.04 and 16.04: Touchpad failed after updating software packages

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, touchpad, dell

I updated my packages on a Dell [Inspiron 3567](https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=Inspiron%203567&sort=relevancy&f:langFacet=%5Ben%5D) with an i5 CPU, then my touchpad stopped working in Ubuntu 18.04.

I also tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 but in that too once I used `sudo apt-get upgrade` and my touchpad would not work after the reboot.

I tried getting help from StackOverflow and many personal websites that looked describing a similar problem to mine. It has been 4 months and I am still facing the problem.

But everything is working fine if I use Ubuntu using the LiveUSB.

Comment: Are you saying that your touchpad worked properly with the LiveUSB installer of Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Using Ubuntu or Xubuntu? Please click [edit] and revise your question, because you chose the Xubuntu tag but mentioned Ubuntu in the question. The different desktop could be relevant to troubleshooting. Also, please click [edit] and advise if the problem also occurs whren booting from an Ubuntu or Xubuntu 18.04.3  Live USB.

Comment: I am so sorry about that as I am a noob in using ubuntu.

And yes using the LiveUSB installer touchpad is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!!

In new update of Ubuntu, this problem is solved.